# Listview adapter doesnt show textview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I got a ListView Adapter. In this adapter , i fill it with some data .My problem is that it shows my date only after i scroll down and don't understand what's the problem , any ideas??

```
public class EventsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Article> {

    EventsAdapter adapter = this;
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Article> cartItems = new ArrayList<Article>();
    Date time;

    public EventsAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                         ArrayList<Article> galleries) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, galleries);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.cartItems = galleries;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Article eventItem = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_item_row, parent, false);
        }

        Typeface cFont2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/berthold_baskerville_bold-webfont.ttf");
        final RecordHolder holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_image);
        holder.eventTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        holder.eventTitleDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_title_description);
        holder.eventCountries = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_countries);
        holder.eventRegions = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_regions);
        holder.eventCategory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_category);
        holder.eventType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_type);
        holder.eventDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        holder.salary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.job_salary);
        holder.eventTitle.setTypeface(cFont2);
        holder.salary.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.eventImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (!eventItem.getImageURL().equals("")) {
            holder.eventImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(eventItem.getImageURL())
                    .resize(250, 175)
                    .into(holder.eventImage);
        }
        holder.eventTitle.setText(eventItem.getName());

        if (eventItem.getCountry() == null) {
            holder.eventCountries.setText(context.getString(R.string.all_countries));
        } else {
            holder.eventCountries.setText(eventItem.getCountry().getName());
        }
        if (eventItem.getRegion() == null) {
            holder.eventRegions.setText(context.getString(R.string.all_regions));
        } else {
            holder.eventRegions.setText(eventItem.getRegion().getName());
        }

        boolean startDate = false;
        boolean endDate = false;
        String endDateString = "";
        String startDateString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < eventItem.getExtraFields().size(); i++) {
            if (eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getName().equals("EVENTENDDATE") && !eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue().equals("")) {
                endDate = true;
                endDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(getDate(eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue()));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < eventItem.getExtraFields().size(); i++) {
            if (eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getName().equals("EVENTSTARTDATE") && !eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue().equals("")) {
                startDate = true;
                startDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(getDate(eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue()));
            }
        }

        if (startDate && endDate) {
            holder.eventDate.setText(startDateString + " - " + endDateString);
            holder.eventDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (startDate) {
            holder.eventDate.setText(startDateString);
            holder.eventDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.eventDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

       for (int i = 0; i < eventItem.getExtraFields().size(); i++) {
            if (eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getName().equals("EVENTORGANISER")) {
                holder.eventTitleDescription.setText(eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue());
            } else if (eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getName().equals("EVENTTYPE")) {

                holder.eventType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.eventType.setText(eventItem.getExtraFields().get(i).getValue().getValue());
            }

        }
        holder.eventCategory.setText(eventItem.getCategories().get(0).getName());

        return convertView;
    }


    private Date getDate(String date) {

        String json = date;
        String timeString = json.substring(json.indexOf("(") + 1, json.indexOf(")"));
        String[] timeSegments = timeString.split("\\+");
        // May have to handle negative timezones
        int timeZoneOffSet = Integer.valueOf(timeSegments[1]) * 36000; // (("0100" / 100) * 3600 * 1000)
        long millis = Long.valueOf(timeSegments[0]);
        time = new Date(millis + timeZoneOffSet);
        return time;
    }

    static class RecordHolder {
        TextView salary;
        ImageView eventImage;
        TextView eventTitle;
        TextView eventTitleDescription;
        TextView eventCountries;
        TextView eventRegions;
        TextView eventCategory;
        TextView eventType;
        TextView eventDate;
    }
}
```

Have i done something wrong or it is an android visual bug ??

**UPDATED:**

event_item_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ebf5fb"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/event_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#043c5b"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_regions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>
    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/event_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>
    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/job_salary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"
        android:text="@string/salary"/>
    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/event_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#7c7f7e"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: probably visual bug,post your xml

Comment: Check whats print ? Log.d("+++++",""+eventItem.getCountry().getName());

Comment: My problem is not in country , but in event_date

Comment: okay,then prints whats type of date format returns ?

Comment: print for date ,say what retuns

Comment: it prints all dates  : 28/07/2014 - 30/07/2015 etc.

Comment: I don't understand why it shows this date only after scrolling down and then up to that date

Answer (score 1):

Got it ,Please update your `null` checking .

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;
        convertView = null;

         if(convertView == null){

          holder = new ViewHolder();
          convertView = inflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.community_common_tab_layout, null);

            holder.DashBoard_Tab_List_Root=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Community_Common_Root);
            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.name.setText( dataArray.get(position).countryName);
        holder.language.setText( dataArray.get(position).language);
        holder.Capital.setText( dataArray.get(position).capital);

        return convertView;

    }


    public static class ViewHolder {

        public  LinearLayout  DashBoard_Tab_List_Root;
        public  TextView        Tv_Badge_View;

     }
}
```

Comment: yes sir , it shows date only after i scroll down and date goes  up , then when i scroll up it appears

Comment: @adminral i tried in here ,Please remove android:visibility="gone" (event_date) from xml .run this

Comment: removed , but same result

Comment: last advise:please create separate layout for which are gone and which are visible,i mean modify your xml layout